# Deserialize BsonDocument to Class type

Tags: c#, mongodb

I was searching some existing solutions but I couldnt fit any here :

Trying to deserialize BsonDocument into Korisnik(class type), so I can perform linq query on collection returned from mongoDB ddb.

```
public List<Korisnik> returnCollection(Korisnik k)
{
List<Korisnik> lista = new List<Korisnik>();
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Korisnik");

//here I want to deserialize BsonDocument to Korisnik

lista = collection.Find(x=>x.Ime == k.Ime).ToList();
return lista;
}
```

---

UPDATE: here is how i fixed it, maybe someone will need that:

```
   var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Korisnik");

   var result = collection.Find(new BsonDocument("name", k.Ime)).ToList();

   for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
   {
       var user = result[i];
       k = new Korisnik();
       k.JMBG = user[0].ToString();
       k.Ime = user[1].ToString();
       k.Prezime = user[2].ToString();
       lista.Add(k);

   }
   return lista;
```

Comment: Did you try `var collection = database.GetCollection< Korisnik >("Korisnik");`

Comment: yes. I got nothing back